# Failed to verify signature of payload: kb2707250

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

When I trying to update Visual Studio 2012 to Update 3 I got this error: "`Failed to verify signature of payload: kb2707250`".

I tried to reinstall VS, tried to update root certificates, I googled it for few days and I really don't know what I have to do to get this bloody Update 3.

Comment: Seems to be a corrupt download or have you tried to disable antivirus software?

Comment: Another possibility: [Go to the Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) and follow the instructions to download locally all the package (/layout option)

Comment: @Steve I downloaded ISO image and tried to install it. Is it the same? Only antivirus I have is microsoft essentials, I will try to disable it and install again.

Comment: I don't know about the ISO image. By the way the [KB2707250](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06b7f509-567b-4869-81a3-801e4cae883f/where-to-download-vsupdatekb2707250exe-as-complete-setup-not-web-installer) seems to be a prerelease of Update1. It is strange that it try to install it. Are you trying to install the update going from no update to update3? In this case I will try to make the upgrade one step at time (yes I know it is terribly slow)

Comment: @Steve yes, I downloaded update 1 and tried to install it, but I got message that I already have greater version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in incorrectly downloaded ISO image. It had right size, but SHA-hash was different from SHA that was provided on download page. So I download it again and it installs correct.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and after scratching my head looking at the logs I found out the reason!

My clock was 1h ahead!
Go figure!
Probably I should thanks DST.

Clock update and install succeeded.